# Need to add syntax color to the Code in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, syntax, wordpress-theming, code-snippets

Need to write code snippet into Wordpress website. Here snippet needs to highlight keywords of the code. Currently, being used language is Verilog. Need solution on how to highlight any code keywords of any language using WordPress addon or theme modification.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a static site generator like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io). It uses [Chroma](https://github.com/alecthomas/chroma) by default for syntax highlighting and (System)Verilog **is** supported in that.

You simply write the code blocks in Markdown as:

````
```systemverilog
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module top;

  initial begin
    $timeformat(-9, 3, " ns", 11); 
    #10.1;
    $display("[%t] Hello", $realtime);
    $finish;
  end

endmodule : top
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But can you help me with WordPress?

Comment: Sorry, I have 0 WordPress experience. I saw that your question was heavily downvoter. So I just answered for "SystemVerilog " + "syntax highlighting " + "blogging " solution :)